# Recording while playing sound in Twilio

Tags: record, playback, twilio

I was wondering if there's any way to record a caller's input while simultaneously playing sound. (Context: I'm trying to build an app that records people singing/rapping along to an instrumental audio track).

I've set up an app that records the user then plays the audio or vice versa, but I'm having trouble getting them to work simultaneously. Is there a way to implement this? I appreciate the help.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give some proof of process? As per [proper SO etiquette](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), you should show what you have tried and ask for assistance in improving your code or filling in the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest looking at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845848/use-say-verb-to-all-conference-participants/17846262#17846262).  It describes how to get Twilio to dial into a `<Conference>` and play a recording into it.  You could combine this with the `<Dial>` verbs [record](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-record) parameter to record the conference call.

Hope that helps.

Comment: "this SO post" — seems you forgot the link.