# How to say/play something to everyone in a call in Twilio

Tags: twilio, phone-call, twilio-twiml

My Twiml is:

> (Dial attributes)
>
> (Number url="_numberURL")_toNumber(/Number)
>
> (Say)Party 2 prompt(/Say)
>
> (/Dial)

Party 2 gets connected after phone is picked up and Party 1, Party 2 can now talk to each other however (Say) verb is never called!! 
Is there a way i can broadcast a (Say) to all users connected in the call?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio evangelist here.

You cannot put the `<Say>` verb inside of the `<Dial>` verb.  If you want to have Twilio say something that both parties hear once they are connected what you will have to do is utilize a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference).  Dial both parties into the conference, then you can have Twilio also dial into that conference and say something.

This post shows a really similar scenario:

[Use Say verb to all Conference participants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845848/use-say-verb-to-all-conference-participants/17846262#17846262)