# How do I Say something after Dialing?

Tags: xml, rest, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am joining two callers together by calling the first and then in the URL Response TwiML I am dialing the second number.  How can I Say a message to both parties after the second phone has picked up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I think this depends on the specific experience you want to give.  For clarity, lets define the two callers as Caller A (the initial caller) and Caller B (the person dialed after Caller A dials in).

**Option A**

So one option could be to Say the message to Caller A before dialing Caller B.  Then when you `<Dial>` Caller B, set the *[url](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-url)* attribute of the [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number) noun which lets you give Twilio some TwiML to execute to Caller B *before* Callers A and B are connected.

The downside to this is the parties will hear the message at different times, and you might not want Caller A to hear the message unless they actually get connected to Caller B.

**Option B**

Another option would be to leverage a `<Conference>`.  With this option when Caller A dials in you drop them into a Conference instead of Dialing Caller B.  Then use the API to make an outbound call to Caller B.  When Caller B answers, you drop them into the same Conference as Caller A.

Once Caller B is added to the conference you can have Twilio itself call into that Conference and Say something into it.  This SO post shows how to Say something into a Conference:

[Use Say verb to all Conference participants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845848/use-say-verb-to-all-conference-participants)

Hope that helps.